# Get selection (highlighted text) string from NSTextView Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstring, nstextview

How can I get the selected text's string from a `NSTextView` as an `NSString`?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since NSTextView is a subclass of NSText, you can use [NSText](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSText) instance methods to figure out the selected string like so:

```
NSString *selected = [[myTextView string] 
                      substringWithRange:[myTextView selectedRange]];
```

Answer (score 7):

An NSText can have more than only one selection. Check it out with TextEditapp: select a string with the mouse while pressing CMD. So you can select as many strings as you want. Therefore I think, a more common solution is to use:

```
NSArray *ranges = [myTextView selectedRanges];
```

and then extract the strings one by one.

Comment: Good call! Keep in mind, though, that this applies only to NSText*View* instances, not just NSText. See [the method documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000373-BCIGJIFD)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5, handling multiple selections of NSTextView**
based on @vauxhall's answer

```
extension NSTextView {
    var selectedText: String {
        var text = ""
        for case let range as NSRange in self.selectedRanges {
            text.append(string[range]+"\n")
        }
        text = String(text.dropLast())
        return text
    }
}

extension String {
    subscript (_ range: NSRange) -> Self {
        .init(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound) ..< index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
extension NSTextView {
    var selectedText: String {
        string[selectedRange()]
    }
}

extension String {
    subscript (_ range: NSRange) -> Self {
        .init(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound) ..< index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)])
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let textView = NSTextView()
print(textView.selectedText)
```

Comment: Warning: NSTextView has a selectedRangeS property because multiple selections can be performed. This code should be adapted.