# How to get the selected string from a NSTextView in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, macos-sierra, nstextview

How to do to get the selected string from a NSTextView in Swift?

```
// create a range of selected text
let range = mainTextField.selectedRange()

// this works but I need a plain string not an attributed string
let str = mainTextField.textStorage?.attributedSubstring(from: range)
```

Maybe I have to add an intermediate step where I get the full string and then apply the range on it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024124/get-selection-highlighted-text-string-from-nstextview-objective-c

Comment: Thank you Mitesh, however I'm programming in Swift not in Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
let str = mainTextField.text.substring(with: range)
```

Edit:

This should work now:

```
let range = mainTextField.selectedRange()     // Returns NSRange :-/ (instead of Range)
let str = mainTextField.string as NSString?   // So we cast String? to NSString?
let substr = str?.substring(with: range)      // To be able to use the range in substring(with:)
```

Comment: But this won't work when there are emojis in UITextView. I got error at this line `mainEditor.textStorage.string[range.lowerBound - 1])`. Caused by `Can't advance past endIndex`. `mainEditor.textStorage.string` print 322, `range.lowerBound - 1` print 323.

Comment: I can't see how the code in your comment refers to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet in the Swift 5. That's not very hard but repeated

```swift
let string = textView.attributedString().string
let selectedRange = textView.selectedRange()
let startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: selectedRange.lowerBound)
let endIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: selectedRange.upperBound)
let substring = textView.attributedString().string[startIndex..<endIndex]

let selectedString = String(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having issues with the selectedRanges() not returning the proper range for an NSTextView, make sure that you have made your NSTextView selectable. I don't know if it's not selectable by default but I had to enable it;
`textView.isSelectable = true`
I was trying this in Swift 5 using @user25917 code sample above and I couldn't get the ranges no matter what. I was getting a visual confirmation the text was selected through highlighting which threw me off. This was driving me mad for a few hours.